# Celery not processing tasks everytime

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am having below configuration for celery

```
celery = Celery(__name__,
    broker=os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', 'redis://'),
    backend=os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', 'redis://'))

celery.config_from_object(APP_SETTINGS)
ssl = celery.conf.get('REDIS_SSL', True)

r = redis.StrictRedis(REDIS_BROKER, int(REDIS_BROKER_PORT), 0, 
        charset='utf-8', decode_responses=True, ssl=ssl)
        db_uri = celery.conf.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')

@celery.task 
def process_task(data):
    #some code here
```

I am calling process task inside API endpoint like
`process_task.delay(data)`

sometimes it's processing tasks sometimes not.

can someone help me to resolve this issue?

I am running worker like `celery worker -A api.celery --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=10`

Answer (score -1):

Once all the worker-processes are busy the new tasks will just sit on the queue waiting for the next idle worker-process to start the task. This is most likely why you perceive this as "not processing tasks everytime". Go through the [monitoring and management](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html) section of the Celery documentation to find how to monitor your Celery cluster. For starters, do `celery worker -A api.celery inspect active` to check the currently running tasks.

Comment: thanks,  Actually it's working fine on my local machine but when I moving it to DEV, some tasks never get executed.